# What are all the available ActionResults for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionresult

What are all the methods that return an ActionResult in ASP.NET MVC as of right now (ie. RedirectToAction, etc.)

I haven't found a good documentation resource that lists this kind of stuff.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267043/all-inbuilt-actionresults-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Found from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult.aspx)

```
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
    System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult
    System.Web.Mvc.EmptyResult
    System.Web.Mvc.FileResult
    System.Web.Mvc.HttpUnauthorizedResult
    System.Web.Mvc.JavaScriptResult
    System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult
    System.Web.Mvc.RedirectResult
    System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult
    System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase
```

Methods on the controller object are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller_methods.aspx)

There is:

```
Content
File
Javascript
Json
PartialView
Redirect
RedirectToAction
RedirectToRoute
View
```

Answer (score 4):

From [ActionResult types in MVC2](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/Contents/Item/Display/199):

- ContentResult – Represents a text result.
- EmptyResult – Represents no
  result.
- FileContentResult – Represents a downloadable file (with the
  binary content).
- FilePathResult – Represents a downloadable file
  (with a path).
- FileStreamResult – Represents a downloadable file
  (with a file stream).
- JavaScriptResult – Represents a JavaScript
  script.
- JsonResult – Represents a JavaScript Object Notation result
  that can be used in an AJAX application.
- PartialViewResult –
  Represents HTML and markup rendered by a partial view.
- RedirectResult
  – Represents a redirection to a new URL.
- RedirectToRouteResult –
  Represents a result that performs a redirection by using the
  specified route values dictionary.
- ViewResult – Represents HTML and
  markup rendered by a view.