# Do MVC action methods require views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Do action methods require a view file (.cshtml)?

Do I have to create one for each method I create, or is it optional?

For example, if I do an HTTP post, and do a redirect to a different action method, a view file is not required, is this correct?

Comment: An ActionResult can return numerous types [refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267043/all-inbuilt-actionresults-in-asp-net-mvc). It depend what you want to do. Not sure what you mean by the last statement. If your doing a post, then it implies you have a view to post from, so the associated GET method would return a view.

Comment: Sometimes I am posting a form from a partialview file, that is why I ask, that is nested within another view.

Comment: You only need a view if your method needs to return a view (i.e. you use `return View();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Correct. You don't need a view for an action.**

In MVC, an action is whatever you make of it; it's taking a request, performing an *action* and returning a response.

What you do in the action is up to you, and there is no requirement for a view to exist or for you to return one.